# Get List item body content, format CanvasContent1

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, content

I'm own a website and I want to display on it Sharepoint data through the rest API.
I managed to get Lists and lists items. But the content of the list item is in the key `CanvasContent1`.
The formatting there do not fit my needs.

Basically I need to display that list items page on my site, the same way it is displayed in Sharepoint.

Is there a way to get the style and layout of that content, or is there a way to get that content in text raw, without html so i can format it as I want on my page.

I'm using https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO library for connecting with Sharepoint API.

Comment: Are you fetching content from site page? Can you show us the REST endpoint you are using to fetch list & items?

Comment: Of course. I'm using the V1 rest API, and fetching items from https://{my_site_subdomain}.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items